# Write and read a file in the internal storage (not in the app package)

Tags: android

I would like to create and read a file in the internal storage (not SD card) but I want a file accessible for the user in the Explorer.

How can I do ?

My code :

```
public void WriteFile(View v) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileout= getActivity().openFileOutput("password.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
            OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
            outputWriter.write("hello");
            outputWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void ReadFile(View v) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn=getActivity().openFileInput("hello.txt");
            InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

            char[] inputBuffer= new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
            String s="";
            int charRead;

            while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
                String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
                s +=readstring;
            }
            InputRead.close();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), s + " ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The user does not have access to what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), except on rooted devices. The user has access to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), which may be labeled on their desktop OS as "internal storage", because Google likes to confuse people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` instead of `MODE_PRIVATE`.